# what is the fastest/easiest way to get from a plain 2D game (e.g. pong) to 3D in XNA?

Tags: xna

I have a question about the way from a 2D game to 3D.

e.g. I have a game like pong which is made in 2D. now I want to make it like 3D, this means:
I want to tilt the plat playground of the game into the back, so it looks like the play field is 3D.

How can I achieve this effect?

Comment: It depends a lot. If you hardcoded lots of things, probably it would be hard. If you made things dynamic, the render system isolated from the gameplay(Entity component system is a good way of doing this) then it should be a trivial task.

Comment: can i find a example of making this somewhere or something equal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate the logic from the renderer.. the game is the same, if you change the renderer it will watched different.

You will have the ball, one 2D renderer will draw a circunference and a 3D renderer will draw a sphere... but the movement and collision logic is the same